# What's the difference between using $this->t('text') and t('text') in a block plugin

Tags: 8, blocks, plugins

I've noticed in many tutorials for constructing block plugins,

```
$this->t('text')
```

is used to create translatable text, especially in the block form function. However using

```
t('text')
```

doesn't produce any errors. Is there any difference between using either of these? And if there isn't, what's best practice?

Comment: see also https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/224665/best-practice-this-t-versus-t

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To be exact on your question: there's **no difference** in internal implementation.

But as a **best practice**, you should be using `$this->t` instead of the global `t` wherever possible. If you check the function, [`t` is returning a new TranslateableMarkup object](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/t/8.4.x).

If your class says `$this->t` is not defined, you can add the [StringTranslationTrait](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21StringTranslation%21StringTranslationTrait.php/trait/StringTranslationTrait/8.4.x) to add the behavior or inject it as a dependency.

> Using this trait will add t() and formatPlural() methods to the class.
>   These must be used for every translatable string, similar to how
>   procedural code must use the global functions t() and
>   \Drupal::translation()->formatPlural(). This allows string extractor
>   tools to find translatable strings.
>
> If the class is capable of injecting services from the container, it
>   should inject the 'string_translation' service and assign it to
>   $this->stringTranslation.

So as a best practice rule, you generally do not want to mix procedural within OOP unless completely unavoidable (e.g. native PHP functions).

Answer (score 4):

The documentation for [t()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/t/8.3.x) states:

> When possible, use the [`\Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\StringTranslationTrait::t()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21StringTranslation%21StringTranslationTrait.php/function/StringTranslationTrait%3A%3At/8.3.x). Otherwise create a new [`\Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21StringTranslation%21TranslatableMarkup.php/class/TranslatableMarkup/8.3.x) object directly.

It doesn't explain the reason for this, but if you look at [the comment on the documentation page](https://api.drupal.org/comment/62813#comment-62813), it will give you a reason for using that trait method, or that class.

> Classes can be tested individually with PHPUnit, which runs without bootstrapping core, but the `t()` function is only available when core is bootstrapped.
>   Using `$this->t()` and `StringTranslationTrait` allows the translation to be mocked, so the class can be tested in isolation with PHPUnit.